# because when sending a base64 file it gives me a 414 error

Tags: laravel, postman

I am sending a base64 file pdf by POST, but it gives me an error that this is too long

code controller
enters the data verifies the type of data that is entered, if it is base64 it assigns it and sends it, if it is html, it converts it to pdf and then to base64 and returns the response in json

```
 public function subirResolucion(Request $req){
    $auth = new CeroPapelAuthenticator();
    $auth->setUri(getenv("AUTH_URI"));
    $auth->setSistema(getenv("AUTH_SYSTEM"));
    $auth->setUser(getenv("AUTH_USER"));
    $auth->setPassword(getenv("AUTH_PASS"));

    $response = $auth->access();
    $auth->setToken($response["token"]);
    $auth->setCookie($response["cookie"]);

    $connector = new GestorDocumentalFactory();
    $gd = $connector->crearCeroPapel();

    $id_documento = $req->input("id_documento");
    $transparencia = $req->input("transparencia");
    $base64 = $req->input("base64"); 
    $html = $req->input("html");
    
    
    
    if(!isset($base64))
    {
    
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    
    $pdfAbase64= base64_encode($mpdf->Output());
    $gd->setArchivo($pdfAbase64);
    }else{
    $gd->setArchivo($base64);
    }
   
    $gd->setIdDocumento($id_documento);
    $gd->setTransparencia($transparencia);
    $gd->setSistema("erp");
    $gd->setAuth($auth);
    $gd- 
    >setUri(getenv("SERVICE_URI")."/api/indap/ws2_obtener.php");
     try {
         $subirResolucion = $gd->subirResolucion();
         return response()->json(
              $subirResolucion 
         );
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         return response()->json([
             "status" => "401",
             "mensaje" => "Ocurrió un error al enviar los 
     mensajes 
     ".$e->getMessage()
         ]);
     }
     }
```

model that sends the data to another system through POST

```
 public function subirResolucion()
{

    
    $filter = [
        'sistema' => $this->getSistema(),
        'id_documento' => $this->getIdDocumento(),
        'transparencia' => $this->getTransparencia(),
        'archivo' => $this->getArchivo(),  
    ];

    $url = $this->getUri() . '?data=' . (string) 
    json_encode($filter);
    SysLogger::info("Request URI", print_r($url, true));

    $header = [ 
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Token ".$this->auth->getToken(),
        "Cookie: ".$this->auth->getCookie()
    ];
    SysLogger::info("Headers to be sent", print_r($header, 
    true));

    $response = Page::post($url, [], '', $header);
     print_r($response);
    SysLogger::info("Full response", print_r($response, true));

    $body = json_decode($response['body']);
   // print_r($body);
    SysLogger::info("Body", print_r($body, true));

    
    return $body;
   

}
```

this is the page.php class

If someone can help me send the data, it still throws me an error
hope this code can help

```
class Page
 {
/**
 * get, obtiene pagina web por metodo get
 * @param  string   $url    URL a la que se hace referencia
 * @param  array    $header Arreglo de cabeceras
 * @param  integer  $timeout Segundos de espera a la pagina
 * @return array    ('body', 'head' 'cookie')
 */
static public function get($url, $header=array(), $timeout=10)
{
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    @curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, true);
    if (count($header)>0) {
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }
    $body=curl_exec($curl_handle);
    $error=curl_error($curl_handle);
    $head=curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    $cookie=@curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
    $str_cookie=self::cookieToString($cookie);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return array('body'=>$body, 'head'=>$head, 
  'cookie'=>$str_cookie, 'error'=>$error);
  }

/**
 * post, obtiene pagina web por metodo post
 * @param  string   $url    URL a la que se hace referencia
 * @param  string   $param  string con la lista de parametros
 * @param  string   $cookie cookie
 * @param  array    $header Arreglo de cabeceras
 * @param  integer  $timeout Segundos de espera a la pagina
 * @return array    ('body', 'head' 'cookie')
 */
static public function post($url, $param, $cookie='', 
$header=array(), $timeout=10)
   {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    @curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
    if ($cookie!='') {
        curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    }
    if (count($header)>0) {
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }
    $body=curl_exec($curl_handle);
    $error=curl_error($curl_handle);
    $head=curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    $cookie=@curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
    $status_code=curl_getinfo($curl_handle, 
     CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
    $str_cookie=self::cookieToString($cookie);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return array('body'=>$body, 'head'=>$head, 
  'cookie'=>$str_cookie, 'error'=>$error, 'status' => 
   $status_code);
    }
```

Comment: a 414 is the URL is too long, first thing to check is make sure its sending via post and not appending the fields to the URL, I think a URL can be 2000 characters, so it must be something like that.

Comment: you're sending by post but in the url and not in the body of the request. Add to your question the code that is sending the file.

Comment: One tip I can give you is do not use `getenv` if you are using Laravel, you must associate your environment variables (use `env`) to a configuration (`config('xxxx')` to get the data back), more info on the [main documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#environment-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you are sending the data in the URL and not as data through the POST request body.  You can see here in the URL construction that you are appending all data to the URL.

```
$filter = [
    'sistema' => $this->getSistema(),
    'id_documento' => $this->getIdDocumento(),
    'transparencia' => $this->getTransparencia(),
    'archivo' => $this->getArchivo(),  
];

$url = $this->getUri() . '?data=' . (string) json_encode($filter);
```

I am not sure of which library you are using to send the request but I would say the 2nd empty array here is probably where you need to post the body data of the post request.

```
Page::post($url, [**Data in here**], '', $header);
```

**Edit

I'm not sure what the Page object does so its hard to say in your current implementation.  But if I was doing it I would just use Laravels built in HTTP Client.

```
$filter = [
    'sistema' => $this->getSistema(),
    'id_documento' => $this->getIdDocumento(),
    'transparencia' => $this->getTransparencia(),
    'archivo' => $this->getArchivo(),  
];

$response = Http::withHeaders([ 
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Token ".$this->auth->getToken(),
    "Cookie: ".$this->auth->getCookie()
])->post($this->getUri(), [
    'data' => (string) json_encode($filter),
]);
```

** Edit 2

As I mentioned in the original answer, the 2nd variable is the parameters for the post body and not the response, this is a common approach, although it looks like you have to set as a string, so I would think you would need to do

```
Page::post($url, (string) json_encode($filter), '', $header);
```

This is the help in the file

```
* @param  string   $param  string con la lista de parametros
```

Comment: Would you have an example to send through the body of the request, thanks for commenting

Comment: the response variable goes in the empty array space, like this ?
Page::post($url, $response, '', $header);

Comment: Are you sure its the response and not the data?  The response variable is only being passed back when this call is made, can you share the code for the Page object?

Comment: I just shared the page of the page object